# Firebase Messaging 7.0.0 to 9.0.1 conversion

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm trying to set up FCM for my iOS flutter app and followed the guide by flutter and even the guide from Fireship.io

I was working with an older version of FCM before I updated the dependencies and now there are methods that are deprecated or just plainly left out. I am unsure of which methods to replace these and I was unable to find resources on what exactly changed in between versions.

Below is my code from FCM 7.0.0

Code:

```
final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
StreamSubscription iosSubscription;
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    iosSubscription = _fcm.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((data) {
      // save the token  OR subscribe to a topic here
    });
    _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings);
  }
}

_saveDeviceToken() async {
  // Get the current user
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
  // FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

  // Get the token for this device
  String fcmToken = await _fcm.getToken();

  // Save it to Firestore
  if (fcmToken != null) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
         .collection('users')
         .doc(uid)
         .collection('tokens')
         .add({
         'token': fcmToken,
         'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), // optional
         'platform': Platform.operatingSystem
      });
  }
}
```

So my problems lie with the onIosSettingsRegistered line and the requestNotificationPermissions.
For both it says that method is not defined, because it has been deprecated or is no longer a valid method. Obviously, before updating my dependencies it worked fine no errors. I'm looking for resources revolving around Firebase cloud Messaging 9.0.1 that might show what was updated and what are the current methods to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Google searches yielded the following results, perhaps you can try a bit harder before posting a question next time:

[**onIosSettingsRegistered** is deprecated](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/4012)

> Usage of the IosNotificationSettings class is now deprecated (currently used with the now deprecated requestNotificationPermissions() method).
>
> Instead of this class, use named arguments when calling requestPermission() and read the permissions back via NotificationSettings.

[**requestNotificationPermissions** deprecated too](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#messaging)

> DEPRECATED: requestNotificationPermissions() has been deprecated in favor of requestPermission().

Comment: @Llama it did lead OP to their solution, so I wouldn't say it's "literally nothing"

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is what lead me to fixing my issues. I'm just outlining below what I pulled from [the guide the other user posted](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/4012)

- FirebaseMessaging() no longer works and instead use
  FirebaseMessaging.instance
- IosNotificationSettings which was used with requestNotificationPermissions() can now be done with just RequestPermission()
- Setting up a FCM.configure no longer works and you should just use FirebaseMessaging.onMessage(), FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp, and FirebaseMessaging.onBackGroundMessage(). The last one can be paired with BkacgroundMessageHandeler in order to set up notifications when the app is closed or suspended.
- And lastly, saving tokens still works the same as 7.0.0 as it does in 9.1.0 so no changes there.

9.1.0 brings null safety to the table so (depending on the rest of your dependencies) you can run the newest version of flutter with null safety with no issues.